# How do I extract the date/year/month from pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm trying to extract year/date/month info from the 'date' column in pandas dataframe. Here is my sample code:

```
from datetime import datetime
def date_split(calendar):
  for row in calendar: 
    new_calendar={}
    listdate=datetime.strptime(row['date'],'%Y-%M-%D')
```

I haven't finished the complete code, but when i test run this part I keep getting error like this:

```
----> 7         listdate=datetime.strptime(row['date'],'%Y-%M-%D')
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Anyone has any idea?

Btw, this is the dataframe I use (calendar_data):

[image]

Comment: validate what `row` and  `row['date']` are.

Answer (score 17):

It seems you need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
print (df['date'].dtype)
object

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print (df['date'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

If need extract [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html), [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and [`day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day.html) to new columns:

```
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```

If need `list` of [`date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html)s:

```
listdate = df['date'].dt.date.tolist()
print (listdate)

[datetime.date(2017, 9, 5), 
 datetime.date(2017, 9, 4),
 datetime.date(2017, 9, 3), 
 datetime.date(2017, 9, 2),
 datetime.date(2017, 9, 1)]
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What is desired output?